# DIR-505 I can ping google.com, but can't view webpage

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

I just bought a dlink DIR-505 to extend my wifi range in my house. While I can connect to the device, configure it in Hotspot mode, and PING an external address (google.com), I can't retrieve a web page.

I'm using a NETGEAR N600 on the 2.4ghz band. The device is NOT configured in a repeater base station mode.

Some more information that could be useful:

- I tried setting a custom DNS (the google public ones) but this didn't help.
- I used my Android phone (Nexus 4) and Chromebook to test the wifi (don't have anything else that is wifi enabled atm).
- I also tried the Repeater mode which just not work at all after configuring the network options. The device just become unavailable.